Azure function :error executing function Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest
H All ,
Getting below error while sending request to azure function from a web app . all hosted local Visual studio 2022

mscorlib: Exception while executing function: FuncToQ. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'req'. Newtonsoft.Json: Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Id', line 1, position 6.

Below is the function signature :
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
                                             [Queue("SalesRequestInbound", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<SalesRequest> SalesRequestQueue,
                                             TraceWriter log)

Trying to send request to Azure Function from Web app controller :
salesRequest.Id = "123";
 using (var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesRequest), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "Application/json"))
 {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:7071/api/FuncToQ", content);
     var returnval= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 }
 return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

trying to receive request in azure function from  simple a web application . Function is used to wrie message into azure queue.

I am able to send message to Azure Queue from Web App using the given code.
I have the below code in Azure function.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp69
{
    public static class FuncToQ
    {
        [FunctionName("FuncToQ")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Queue("salesrequestinbound", Connection = "QueueConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> salesRequestQueue,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            if (data?.Id == null)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a valid sales request in the request body");
            }

            await salesRequestQueue.AddAsync(requestBody);

            return new OkObjectResult($"Sales request {data.Id} enqueued successfully");
        }
    }
}

I am using below code in Web App to call the Azure Function.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _78779137.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly HttpClient client;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            client = httpClient;
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "SendSalesRequest")]
        public async Task<string> SendSalesRequest(SalesRequest salesRequest)
        {
            salesRequest.Id = "123";

            using (var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:7168/api/FuncToQ", content);
                var returnval = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return "Sales request enqueued successfully.";
                }
                else
                {
                    return $"Failed to enqueue sales request: {returnval}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class SalesRequest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}

I am able to write message to azure queue.

Functions:

        FuncToQ: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7168/api/FuncToQ

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-07-23T06:59:08.683Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-07-23T07:12:50.066Z] Executing 'FuncToQ' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=0c34ef3c-8031-4d33-996d-6c80f269f6c8)
[2024-07-23T07:12:50.091Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-07-23T07:12:51.202Z] Executed 'FuncToQ' (Succeeded, Id=0c34ef3c-8031-4d33-996d-6c80f269f6c8, Duration=1245ms)



I can see  it doing the same thing . i am not sure why I m getting binding  error .

@Mitali Please check if you have added all the relevant packages? Have you installed Newtonsoft.Json? Please share your .csproj file

It looks like everything I have done  is similar . Why I am getting this error then .

Please share your .csproj file
